# Quick silly question on functions

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Suppose we have a function $f:X\rightarrow Y$, and $A\subset X$, $B\subset Y$.

Is this true: if $B\subset f(A)$ , then $f^{-1}(B)\subset A\subset f^{-1}(f(A)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not true.

Take $X=\{0,1,2\}$ and $Y=\{0,1\}$. Now take $f(0)=f(1)=0, f(2)=1$. $A=\{1\}$ and $B=\{0\}$ then $B=f(A)$ but $f^{-1}(B)$ is a strictly larger set than $A$.

Comment: To complete Asaf's answer: if $f$ is one-to-one, then $f^{-1}(B)\subset A$. Also, $A\subset f^{-1}(f(A))$ is always true.

Answer (score 2):

Nonetheless, it *is* true that

1. $f(A) \subseteq B \iff A \subseteq f^{-1}(B).$
2. $f(f^{-1}(B)) \subseteq B, \;\; A \subseteq f^{-1}(f(A))$

**Exercise.** Show that (1) and (2) are equivalent, then choose one of them and prove it.